# Python regex with *?

Tags: python, regex

What does this Python regex match?

```
.*?[^\\]\n
```

I'm confused about why the `.` is followed by both `*` and `?`.

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html *Laziness Instead of Greediness*.

Comment: or http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy if you are feeling *particularly lazy* today. badum-tsh

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`*` means "match the previous element as many times as possible (zero or more times)".

`*?` means "match the previous element as few times as possible (zero or more times)".

The other answers already address this, but what they don't bring up is how it changes the regex, well if the `re.DOTALL` flag is provided it makes a huge difference, because `.` will match line break characters with that enabled.  So `.*[^\\]\n` would match from the beginning of the string all the way to the ***last*** newline character that is not preceeded by a backslash (so several lines would match).

If the `re.DOTALL` flag is not provided, the difference is more subtle, `[^\\]` will match everything other than backslash, including line break characters.  Consider the following example:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "foo\n\nbar"
>>> re.findall(r'.*?[^\\]\n', s)
['foo\n']
>>> re.findall(r'.*[^\\]\n', s)
['foo\n\n']
```

So the purpose of this regex is to find non-empty lines that don't end with a backslash, but if you use `.*` instead of `.*?` you will match an extra `\n` if you have an empty line following a non-empty line.

This happens because `.*?` will only match `fo`, `[^\\]` will match the second `o`, and the the `\n` matches at the end of the first line.  However the `.*` will match `foo`, the `[^\\]` will match the `\n` to end the first line, and the next `\n` will match because the second line is blank.

Answer (score 6):

`.` indicates a wild card. It can match anything except a `\n`, unless the appropriate flag is used.

`*` indicates that you can have 0 or more of the thing preceding it.

`?` indicates that the preceding quantifier is lazy. It will stop searching after the first match it finds.

Comment: `.` doesn't match `\n` however.

Comment: @MarcusRecck -- Doesn't that depend on the flags you pass?  Doesn't it match if you pass `re.DOTALL` or something like that...

Comment: @JonClements -- Phew!  I thought so.  I'm not a regex guru (although I do almost have a bronze badge for that one), but I like the affirmation that I know a little about them :-)

Comment: @MarcusRecck Forgot about `\n`, thanks. Added it in to my answer.

Comment: So, the `.*?` will match anything except a `\n` for any number of characters, until it hits something that's not a backslash, followed by a newline. Is that correct?

Answer (score 5):

Opening the [Python re module documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html), and searching for `*?`, we find:

> **`*?`, `+?`, `??`**:
>
> The `*`, `+`, and `?` qualifiers are all greedy; they match as much text as possible. Sometimes this behaviour isn’t desired; if the RE `<.*>` is matched against `<H1>title</H1>`, it will match the entire string, and not just `<H1>`. Adding `?` after the qualifier makes it perform the match in non-greedy or minimal fashion; as few characters as possible will be matched. Using `.*?` in the previous expression will match only `<H1>`.